# How can I return the rendered HTML of a Svelte component?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm having a tough time making a tooltip that runs off `use:action`. My requirements are:

1. Create a tooltip with HTML or a Component as the content
2. Without having to wrap a component in a `<Tooltip><element></Tooltip>`
3. Hook in to premade libraries for flexibility

Please see my example code below. It doesn't work in the REPL due to Tippy.js dependencies, but I do have it working with simple HTML in my app. This is why my thinking is that I should seek to render a component, which acknowledges props like any other, then somehow take its HTML and put it in use:action call. (see "content: '**Hey I work!**'") It should be as simple to use as in the days of jQuery's tooltips.

REPL link:
https://svelte.dev/repl/e8fdf98eb42445e3b791d7c908581a71?version=3.17.3

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To really "return the rendered HTML", you'd need to compile with [`generate: 'ssr'` option](https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_compile), and use the `Cmp.render()` function. But you cannot use such a component in the DOM...

You can't really get the content of a component, but you can get the HTML of any element using an action like such:

```html
<script>
const logHtml = el => {
  console.log(el.innerHTML)
}
</script>

<div use:logHtml> ... </div>
```

Or, simply, `bind:this` on elements:

```html
<script>
  let el
  $: if (el) console.log(el.innerHTML)
</script>

<div bind:this={el}> ... </div>
```

In your case, though, it seems that what you want is to render the component directly into the tooltip's element. You can use [`new MyComponent`](https://svelte.dev/docs#Client-side_component_API) for that.

Here's an example action rendering a custom component with `tippy.js` (see [updated REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7563f00e70e8448bab94bae4ab1b48c5?version=3.17.3)):

```js
export function tipz(elem, { content, props, ...opts }) {
  let cmp

  const tp = tippy(elem, {
    onCreate() {
      cmp = new content({
        target: instance.popper.querySelector(".tippy-content"),
        props,
      });
    },
    ...opts
  })

  return {
    update(params) {
      // ensure reactivity
      if (cmp) {
        cmp.$set(params.props)
      }
    },
    destroy() {
      tp.destroy();
      if (cmp) {
        // cleanup component
        cmp.$destroy();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot just from your answer. It's working now but there were two problems:

1. I was getting a weird `__update` error. Turns out Svelte 3.16.7 had a use:action bug in it, fixed in 3.17.0!
2. I had to modify the onCreate to additionally pass `, props` because it seemed to not be created with them. Updated REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/ffd2b212ae9e48e4b0279e72c1c7cb21?version=3.17.3

Comment: Oh, you're right, you need to pass the props at component creation too. I fixed the code example. Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed this instantiates the component on init, meaning if I have 50 elements on the page, it makes 50 components. Any idea if it's possible to use `new MyComponent` without this happening?

Comment: Yes, it's be possible. It mainly depends on your lib providing the right hooks. For example, with tippyjs, you can create the `new Cmp` on `onShow` hook, and `$destroy` it on `onHidden`.

`new Cmp` will render to the DOM synchronously, so you don't have to worry about the content flickering because the component is rendered too late.

The one thing to worry about maybe, if you create the component only when the tooltip is shown, is that you'll probably have to store new props arriving through `update` in a local var or something, to be sure that the component is created with latest values.