# How to get html element of Svelte component using bind:this?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, svelte-3

Suppose I have a reusable component called `button.svelte`,

```
<script>
export let text = undefined
</script>

<button>{text}</button>
```

Now I reuse this component in another component like so,

```
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte"
import Button from "./Button.svelte"

let button

onMount(() => {
    console.log(button) // How do I print the html of the button element?
})
</script>

<Button text="Button" bind:this="{button}"></Button>
```

But `button` of `bind:this` doesn't seem to have the html of the button element. How do I get the html element of the button?

Comment: Did you try innerHTML on button inside console.log? Also bind:this isn't supposed to be without double quotes?

Comment: May be this can help : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889859/how-can-i-return-the-rendered-html-of-a-svelte-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59889859/how-can-i-return-the-rendered-html-of-a-svelte-component)

Comment: @JulienGabriel I tried doing `button.innerHTML` but shows `undefined`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To achieve this you have to do 2 things

- bind element to prop using `bind:this={prop}`.
- access the element in the parent component via the bonded prop and the important part is that you must do that in a reactive statement `$:`.

Button.svelte

```
<script>
    export let node
</script> 

<button bind:this={node}>
  <slot />
</button>
```

import Button component

```
<script>
    import Button from './Button.svelte'
    let button
    
    $:console.log(button)
</script>

<Button bind:node={button}>
    Hello
</Button>
```